# Omega Theme Renders a Container inside of a Container

Tags: theming

I currently have a view listing a set of products via rendered entities as Teasers. However the Omega Theme is taking each teaser and adding the container-24 class to it eliminating the ability for me to have the teasers display inline. Below is an image attached, why is Omega doing this?

[http://i.imgur.com/H1izEsp.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/H1izEsp.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I have seen that before with Omega 3 - its presuming too much :)
What you can do to work around this, is get the node template file, and create a template file for a teaser mode, and reference it in template.php. One sample of doing that is here: [What is the template suggestion for node 'teaser' view mode?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27974/drupal-7-template-suggestion-for-node-teaser-view-mode)