# Wich template name do I need for the advanged forum teaser view mode?

Tags: theming, entities, nodes

I have two different view_modes for a adv. forum post: in the node (full) and in a view_block with the teaser display suite view mode.
With template advanced-forum-post.tpl.php I can change both view_modes.

I can't find a way to make two seperated tpl.php templates, one for full_mode and one for teaser_mode. E.g node--contentype--view_mode.tpl.php is not working. I tried [What is the template suggestion for node 'teaser' view mode?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27974/drupal-7-template-suggestion-for-node-teaser-view-mode): with no result.
Does anybody knows the answer?